# Chrome iPad has wrong viewport height

Tags: google-chrome, ipad, viewport

I have a strange behavior on Chrome browser (v 95.0.4638.50) on iPad (iPadOS 15.0).

I have a first website (let's call it "A") and a second website (called "B"). A has a link to B which will open in a new tab.

The issue is that when B opens in a new tab, it looks like the viewport is bigger than the iPad's screen because my footer (which is `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`) is below the visible part and I have to scroll to see it.

Fun facts about this:

- if I go back to the first tab (A) and returns to the second one (B), everything goes back to normal
- I tested with Safari, Firefox and even Edge and the bug only appears in Chrome

Here is how my page is displayed after first load:

[image: Figure1]

Then if I scroll a bit, I reach the bottom of the page and I finally see the footer:

[image: Figure 2]

And when I switch tabs and come back, everything is back to normal:

[image: Figure 3]

Do you know any way to tell Chrome to resize the page correctly ?

Comment: I'm having this exact issue right now. Could you please share how u solved this? The adding -webkit-fill-available doesn't work for me.

Comment: I'm able to create a sample app for this issue. https://github.com/nuynait/test-window-open

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's Chrome's bugs.
But I tried to fix that in this way.
First, you need to create an input element and set it hidden like this one (I used tailwindcss):

```html
<div class="fixed top-0 left-0 p-4 bg-gray-50 z-[-1] flex flex-col gap-4">
  <input type="text" id="test" />
</div>
```

After that, you add an event listener for the document and handle it like this one

```js
const handleFirstTouch = () => {
  let test = document.getElementById('test');
  test.focus();
  setTimeout(() => {
    test.blur();
    document.removeEventListener('touchstart', handleFirstTouch);
  }, 0);
}

    
document.addEventListener('touchstart', handleFirstTouch);
```

Hope it can help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `dvh` units instead of `vh`:

```css
height: 100dvh;
```

More info about the new units: [The large, small, and dynamic viewport units | web.dev](https://web.dev/blog/viewport-units#the-need-for-new-viewport-units).

Comment: This is already applied and is not solving this bug. It's exclusive to Chrome iOS and does not occurs in Safari iOS nor Firefox iOS so it's probably not gonna be solved with CSS

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Try modifying height like so

```
height: calc(100vh - 65px); 65px
```

Or **Option 2:**  try this Option 2 with `-webkit-fill-available`

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* mobile viewport bug fix */
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}
```

There was [a tweet on this](https://twitter.com/bfgeek/status/1262459015155441664)